# Using Google Apps Script to find specific value and then filling a cell in the same row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on this script in which I get values from an external API and fill some columns.
It's working alright, I can get all the values and set them in a spreadsheet ok.

The trick is, I want those values to be set on the cell based on another cell in the same row value.

Let me clarify, the API gives me the values from A to Z. So the column is filled top to bottom A > Z.
But I will try to use this function on another spreadsheet which already contains some values, in which one of them is a field from the API response. So I want to make it match.

Now the sheet is being filled this way:

```
ID    NAME   VALUE
32    A      100
60    B      0
14    C      250
```

And let say my spreadsheet is like this:

```
ID    TYPE      NAME    VALUE (to be filled from the script)
60    type1
14    type1
32    type2
```

I want the values to be set in the same order as the ID, so i would need to do some kind of VLOOKUP to fill the cell acording to it's ID.

My code looks like this now:

```
function atRoe() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var date = new Date();                                              

  var url = "http://url1.com";
  var token = "token";
  var payload = {
    "token":token
  }
  var params = {"method":"POST",
                "contentType":'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                "payload":JSON.stringify(payload),
                "muteHttpExceptions":true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);


  var dado = data["dados"];                                             
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, dado.length,4);
  range.clearContent();
  var values = range.getValues();

   for (i = 0; i <= dado.length; i++){
    var id = dado[i]['Id'].toString();                                 
    var nome = dado[i]['Nome'];                                
    Logger.log("Carregando: " + i + " / " + dado.length)

 
    var url = "http://url2.com";
    var token = "token";
    var dataReferencia = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT-3", "MM/yyyy").toString(); 
    var urlvalid = url + "?token=" + token + "&id=" + id + "&date=" + dataReferencia;

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlvalid);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data_clin = JSON.parse(json);


    if (data_clin["dataObject"].length >= 1){                           
      var fat_orto = data_clin["dataObject"][0]["totaL_ORTODONTIA"]      
      var fat_impl = data_clin["dataObject"][0]["implante"]             
      var fat_prot = data_clin["dataObject"][0]["protese"]          
      var fat_clin = data_clin["dataObject"][0]["clinico"]   
      var filial = data_clin["dataObject"][0]["cd_filial"]

      var fat_total = fat_orto + fat_clin + fat_impl + fat_prot;
    }
    else{
      var fat_total = 0;
      var filial = "ERRO";
    };
    values[i][0] = filial;
    values[i][1] = nome;
    values[i][2] = fat_total;
    values[i][3] = id;

    range.setValues(values);
   };
};
```

What can I do? I'm kinda stuck

Comment: Probably you can convert your destination array in an object where 'IDs' are keys and rows are its values. Additionally you need to add value 'counter' to every row to preserve the original order. After that you can fill values of the object: `obj[ID] = [counter, filial, nome, fat_total, id]` , and to convert the object back into an array. And then to sort the array by 'counter' value `array = array.sort((a, b) => (a[0] - b[0]))` to restore its order. New `IDs` (without 'counters') will get in bottom or top of the list). Before `setRange()` you need to remove the 'counters' from the array.

Comment: You can use TextFinder in apps script. Select the range where your IDs'. Create a textfinder from the range selected. Find a specific id in the range. It will return a range object. Use that to get the row where you want to insert your data. You can provide a sample sheet which includes your expected output & sample input data if you need further assistance

Comment: Show us an example of what you get from the API and how you wish it displayed in the spreadsheet and how that display is correlated to another value in a spreadsheet.